# Nagios escalation debugging

Tags: configuration, nagios

I'm having some issues with escalations happening properly and I'm not sure if it's because of my config or because the nagios binary is nonstandard and something may be broken. I've got little experience with nagios, and just want to make sure this is being set appropriately.

Should the following config file definition allow the escalations to take over and increment the notification interval as expected? Is there somewhere else in the config files I should be looking at to figure out what's going on? I've enabled debug 32 in the config and it's simply spitting out 'Host notification will NOT be escalated.' for each notification.

The configuration does pass the pre flight check with no issues, and reports that it's parsing the three host escalations in the config.

```
# test host definition
define host {
    host_name   test
    alias       test
    address     10.0.0.10
    hostgroups  test
    check_interval  0
    retry_interval  1
    max_check_attempts 2
    flap_detection_enabled  0
    icon_image  windows.png
    icon_image_alt  LOGO - Windows
    vrml_image  windows.png
    statusmap_image windows.png
    action_url  /info/host/275
    check_period    24x7
    contact_groups  hostgroup15_servicegroup1,hostgroup15_servicegroup10,hostgroup15_servicegroup13,hostgroup15_servicegroup14,hostgroup15_servicegroup2,hostgroup15_servicegroup3,hostgroup15_servicegroup4,hostgroup15_servicegroup42,hostgroup15_servicegroup45,hostgroup15_servicegroup46,hostgroup15_servicegroup47,hostgroup15_servicegroup5,hostgroup15_servicegroup8,hostgroup15_servicegroup9,ov_monitored_by_master
    check_command       check_host_15!-H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 3 -w 500.0,80% -c 1000.0,100%
    parents nagios
    notifications_enabled   1
    notification_interval   3
    notification_period 24x7
    notification_options    u,d,r
    use host-global
}

define hostescalation{
    host_name               test
    first_notification      3
    last_notification       4
    notification_interval   10
    contact_groups          hostgroup15_servicegroup1,hostgroup15_servicegroup10,hostgroup15_servicegroup13,hostgroup15_servicegroup14,hostgroup15_servicegroup2,hostgroup15_servicegroup3,hostgroup15_servicegroup4,hostgroup15_servicegroup42,hostgroup15_servicegroup45,hostgroup15_servicegroup46,hostgroup15_servicegroup47,hostgroup15_servicegroup5,hostgroup15_servicegroup8,hostgroup15_servicegroup9,ov_monitored_by_master
}

define hostescalation{
    host_name               test
    first_notification      4
    last_notification       5
    notification_interval   30
    contact_groups          hostgroup15_servicegroup1,hostgroup15_servicegroup10,hostgroup15_servicegroup13,hostgroup15_servicegroup14,hostgroup15_servicegroup2,hostgroup15_servicegroup3,hostgroup15_servicegroup4,hostgroup15_servicegroup42,hostgroup15_servicegroup45,hostgroup15_servicegroup46,hostgroup15_servicegroup47,hostgroup15_servicegroup5,hostgroup15_servicegroup8,hostgroup15_servicegroup9,ov_monitored_by_master
}

define hostescalation{
    host_name               test
    first_notification      5
    last_notification       0
    notification_interval   240
    contact_groups          hostgroup15_servicegroup1,hostgroup15_servicegroup10,hostgroup15_servicegroup13,hostgroup15_servicegroup14,hostgroup15_servicegroup2,hostgroup15_servicegroup3,hostgroup15_servicegroup4,hostgroup15_servicegroup42,hostgroup15_servicegroup45,hostgroup15_servicegroup46,hostgroup15_servicegroup47,hostgroup15_servicegroup5,hostgroup15_servicegroup8,hostgroup15_servicegroup9,ov_monitored_by_master
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition was correct, but nagios was using a precached object model so changes to the config files didn't have any effect on a reload. Regenerating the precache resolved the issue.

Comment: To regen precache, call with the p option; /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -pv /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg . For more, see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/01/nagios-command/